# Render HTML file into view - MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, rendering

I upload a Html file with Dropzone.js, as into site examples :

```
//Upload view
@using System.Text;
@{
    Layout = null;
    string path = ViewBag.path;
}
@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dropzone")
    <form action="@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneJsForm"></form>
    <button id="submit-all">Submit All Files</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {
            //prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            init: function () {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
                var myDropzone = this; //closure
                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    //tell Dropzone to process all queued files
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                });

            }
        };

    </script>
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(File.ReadAllText(path)))
}

//HomeController
public ActionResult Upload()
       {

           foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
           {
               HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
               if (file.ContentLength > 0)
               {
                   var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                   file.SaveAs(path);
                   ViewBag.path = path;
               }
           }
           return View();

       }
```

The file was saved,the view can read it but the page did not display anything.
I can not figure out what's not working. If I active the debugger seems that everything is ok but in the end the page did not draw the html tag of the file. Can you help me or suggest a possible solution

Thank you so much

Comment: Why are you using HtmlDecode? Encode seems to me more right (but probably not your main problem here).

Comment: Have you looked into the rendered page source? Maybe your content is rendered as part of a previously opened tag and therefore hidden?

Comment: Tnx Chris i've updated the question can you give me some help?

Comment: No sorry, dont see the problem. Have you looked into the rendered page source? Maybe you will get closer to a solution, when you first try to access a local test-file which you place in your web. If this works, combine it with the download functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead HttpUtility.HtmlDecode, can you please check **HttpUtility.UrlDecode**, assuming your file is pure html, not html characters.

Comment: Palak! Works! i cannot give you vote because i'm new but you have solved the question! Tnx

Comment: it's fine @MVCisMyBestFriend. happy coding :)